# Input unfocus after typing something in it, i put an onChange function that sets a state using setstate(react hooks) (TextField material ui)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

When using a setting a state((useState() / setState()), the input unfocuses, idk why?
pls help

React hook State

```
 const [username, setUsername] = useState("");
```

this is the my own component which returns a textfield but with my own styles

```
  function FormInput({ onChange, ...rest }) {
    const classes = formInputStyles();

    return (
      <div>
        <TextField
          onChange={(e) => onChange(e.target.value)}
          InputProps={{ classes, disableUnderline: true }}
          {...rest}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
```

Like, i said in the title whenever i type something in the input field it unfocuses and clears the input field.

It dosen't unfocus when i use the normal < TextField > from material ui.
i tried making a whole new function for setting state but that didnt work

```
<FormInput
onChange={(value) => {
setUsername(value);
 }}
label="Username"
variant="filled"
></FormInput>
```

Comment: I can't reproduce from what you described. Please fork this [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-xosz4?file=/demo.tsx) and recreate the behavior so others can help you.

Comment: @NearHuscarl go to this link first <a href="https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-xosz4?file=/demo.tsx">your codesandbox</a>  ok i found the reason its because i put the FormInput Function inside the BasicTextField function i put all the styles and all the function inside the main function which renders the app (BasicTextField) anyway, thanks man your the reason i found this solution, thanks man